# How to put an error when my textInputLayout is empty

Tags: java, kotlin, textinput, android-textinputlayout

I am carrying out addition of decimals with textInputLayout, the problem is that at the moment of calling isEmpty () to show an error in case the fields are empty, this option does not appear.

I want to do it this way

```
 button.setOnClickListener {


            val numberOne = textInputLayout.editText?.text.toString().toDouble()
            val numberTwo = textInputLayout2.editText?.text.toString().toDouble()
            val reult = numberOne + numberTwo

            if (numberOne./*no appears isEmpty*/){
              textInputLayout.error = ("enter number")
            }else
                if (numberTwo./*no appears isEmpty*/){
                    textInputLayout2.error = ("enter number")
                }else {
                    textView.text = reult.toString()
                }
            
        }
```

xmlns

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:hint="@string/numero"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:hint="@string/numero2"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                .../>
```

And you can check the value with:

```
val double: Double? = textInputLayout.editText?.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
val double2: Double? = textInputLayout2.editText?.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
    
if (double != null){
      //Double1 is a number
      textInputLayout.error = ""
      if (double2 != null){
         //Double2 is a number
          textInputLayout2.error = ""
          textview.text = (double+double2).toString()
       } else {
          //Double2 is not a number
          textInputLayout2.error = "Error"
           textview.text = ""
       }
 } else {
     //Double1 is not a number
     textInputLayout.error = "Error"
     textview.text = ""
 }
```

Comment: Ready the errors are reflected but I do not know how to add the numbers and show the result

Comment: Just move your logic in the `//Number is double`

Comment: I did this :  val double: Double? = number1.editText?.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        double?.let {
            // Number is double....

        } ?: (number1.setError("Enter number")  )

        val double2: Double? = number1.editText?.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()
        double2?.let {
            // Number is double....
        } ?: (number2.setError("Enter number")  )

Comment: I did it like this so that the error appears in both fields, sorry I am a beginner

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo Check the updated answer. You can do it in some different ways.

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration but the error is reflected only in the textInputLayout2

Comment: @JorgeLeonardo Rewritten the answer in easier way

Answer (score 0):

numberOne and numberTwo are double
val numberOne = textInputLayout.editText?.text.toString().**toDouble()**

isEmpty() is a string function
try numberOne.toString().isEmpty() and same for numberTwo

Comment: ok then you can try to declare num1,num2 as a string and result convert to double
something like this

val numberOne = textInputLayout.editText?.text.toString()
            val numberTwo = textInputLayout2.editText?.text.toString()
            val reult = numberOne.toDouble() + numberTwo.toDouble();